# Correct way of mounting a Windows share

Tags: windows, mount, permissions, fstab

I mounted a Windows share to my Ubuntu 11.10 system via adding the following line to the `/etc/fstab`:

`//serveraddr/sharedfolder /mnt/foldername/ smbfs credentials=/home/myname/.smbpasswd 0 0`

using the [tutorial here](http://www.justlinux.com/nhf/Filesystems/Mounting_smbfs_Shares_Permanently.html).

But there's a problem with the permissions. The owner of the mount folder is `root`. I can not create any folders or files in the mounted point is I don't become the root. Even I can not change the ownership to my default user via

`sudo chown -R myname .`

I googled and saw that it might stem from the fact that Windows file formats (fat32/ntfs) can not save ownership. But when I connect to the same location via samba as

`smb://serveraddr/sharedfolder`

by providing my credentials, I have the privileges to write without being the root.

How can I make it to let me write to the mounted folder?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't use `smbfs`, the new protocol's name is `cifs` and its part of the package `cifs-tools` (install it if you did not already.

Instead use this line in your `fstab`

```
//server/share /mnt/mountname cifs username=server_user,password=user_password,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=07‌​77 0 0
```

Where

```
server = your server that you are trying to access
share = mapped share on that server
/mnt/mountname = any folder that you created with sudo /mnt/<folder_name>
username = the name of the user on that server that can access the mount
password = the password for that user
```

After that you can test with `sudo mount -a`, if you dont get any faults you can safely reboot to find your shares mounted in `/mnt/<folder_name>`.

To use a credentials file instead of the `username` and `password` parameters on the `fstab` you can create a file with those 2 lines so that your username and password are not explicitly shown in the fstab

`sudo nano /etc/cifspwd`

Add these lines to the file

```
username=<username on server>
password=<password for that username>
```

Press ctrl+x keys and when asked press `y` to save the file.

Secure it with

`sudo chmod 600 /etc/cifspwd`

Use this line instead of the previous

```
//server/share /mnt/mountname cifs credentials=/etc/cifspwd,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=07‌​77 0 0
```

After this it will be safe to reboot and you mount should be mounted and your details secured.

Comment: If this does not work please paste the output of `cat ~/.smbpasswd`.

Comment: @bbrunopereira81: It doesn't work. `cat .smbpasswd` gives  
`user=name.surname
pass=*******
dom=domainname`

Comment: @İsmailArı why do you have domain? are you part of a domain??? try using all on the same line instead of making a file apart for the credentials, try this on a terminal: `sudo mount -t cifs //ip_from_windows_pc/sharename /mnt/share -o username=windows_username,password=windows_password_for_user,iocharset=utf8,file_‌​mode=0777,dir_mode=0777`. if you get faults write them down.

Comment: ps: its all one line!

Comment: @bbrunopereira81: It works fine after doing within the terminal. The files can be editable.

Comment: great, now all you need to do is add this to your fstab: `//server/share /mnt/mountname cifs username=server_user,password=user_password,iocharset=utf8,mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0' after the line is there just mount everything with `sudo mount -a`.

Comment: edited the answer to reflect the information you gave. btw dont forget that if /mnt/<mountname> is already in use you need to `umount /mnt/<mountname>`, `mountname` can be any folder that you create with `sudo mkdir /mnt/<folder>`.

Comment: welcome, gl and hf ;)

Comment: Added information for the credentials file, you can also use that method.

Comment: Actually, I've done it that way :)

Comment: @İsmailArı good, good. anyways gl!

Comment: I think it's worth noting that in Ubuntu 12.10, "mode" was not a valid parameter. Instead, I had to use "file_mode". Also, I'm  not sure I entirely agree with general permissions of 0777. If you're mounting a private share just for yourself, I think something like "file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Avian00 kk, thanks for the mode, will review that. About permissions: well that depends on what needs to be done, not for discussion here I would say.

Comment: Confirming that "mode" should be replaced with "file_mode" in 12.10!

Comment: On 12.04 I had to add `,nounix` to my options for it to work.  Full working solution for me is: `//server/share /mnt/mountname cifs credentials=/etc/cifspwd,iocharset=utf8,mode=0777,dir_mode=07‌​77,nounix 0 0`

Comment: Is there a way to have the credentials file use an encrypted hash for your password?  Even with the permissions set to 600, any system admin with sudo privileges would be able to read my password in plain text.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoPereira do you know how to change a user owner of the folder? `sudo chown <myname> /path/to/mounted/share` does not change the `root` owner

Comment: answering my own question: add `uid=user_id,gid=group_id` to the list of options into the fstab

Comment: These days, the package name for `cifs` seems to be `cifs-utils`.