# How do I map Network Drives?

Tags: networking, windows, drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct way of mounting a Windows share](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72471/correct-way-of-mounting-a-windows-share)

I was wondering if it was possible to map windows network drives on Ubuntu. If there is any way, please let me know how!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

By default in Nautilus you can see all your drives in the left Panel. Just click on it and your drive will be accessible:

Here is a pic from wiki as to how nautilus looks like:

[image]

There are also manual mount solutions:

Check out:

```
umount --help
```

But I think in your case  a GUI is the preferred way.

Cheers