# How to mount a shared folder of a windows system in Ubuntu Permanently?

Tags: mount, automount

I need to mount a shared folder of a windows system in ubuntu with `read / write` permission permanently. How do i do that?

#### Note:

- The windows system is connected to domain.
- Say the ubuntu system has only one user account without sudo permission. We use root account for system modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Start by CIFS installation.  To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Once done you need to mount network folders.  For complete instructions and how to, see the [Mount Windows Shares Permanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)</sup>

Comment: I ve done these steps already. But write permissions were not present. I am not able write anything.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72471/correct-way-of-mounting-a-windows-share), and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/471859/write-permission-when-mounting-windows-shares-from-ubuntu).

Comment: When adding the entry to `/etc/fstab` make sure you set `uid=user,gid=group` and replace user and group with the appropriate user and group that you want the files to be placed under ownership. Ex: `//[server]/[share] /home/[user]/[folder] cifs credentials=/home/[user]/.[credentialFile],uid=[user],gid=[group] 0 0`