# Copy a file from ubuntu server to a nas drive

Tags: server, 10.04, scripts, nas, smb

I would like to use a script to copy a sql file to a nas drive location.

for example it would copy backup.sql to //10.1.1.124/backup/Backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mount this shared directory to your system .

This would help you : [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72471/correct-way-of-mounting-a-windows-share)

Then try :

```
cp -r /sql/filename /mountpoint
```

Change the options as your needs .
Dont for get to make your script executable .