# cd desktop to folder on desktop

Tags: command-line, directory, shared-folders

In terminal, I need to do `cd desktop` then `cd data` then `ls data`. `Data` is a folder that connects windows partition of the computer to ubuntu.

`cd Desktop` was initially giving me an error (`bash: cd: no such file or directory`). I instead typed `cd ~/Desktop`, which worked. However, I cannot use `cd data` and I get the same error as before. I even tried `cd ~/data`. It does not work. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Linux filesystems are (generally) case sensitive - so `Desktop` is not the same thing as `desktop`. Is the folder called `data` or `Data`?

Comment: folder is `data`

Comment: I was able to do `ls` for the  `desktop`. The  `data` folder comes up red with black background which means the link is broken. Our computer savvy professor is away and he set up the link. If anyone knows how to reset up the linked folder (connects Windows partition to Ubuntu partition) please let me know.

Comment: Depends on where the NTFS (Windows) folder is; on the same PC or a network share? Sounds like a possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/72471/correct-way-of-mounting-a-windows-share or https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically/300426#300426

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a program to mount all of my drives automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically)

Comment: The tilde (`~`) is short for your home folder (`$HOME`), so `~/data` is not what you want. You could use `~/Desktop/data` instead.

Comment: Regarding the linked folder, please post the output of `readlink ~/Desktop/data` (get the symlink's destination) and the contents of `/etc/fstab` (the filesystem table).

Comment: `readlink ~/Desktop/data` yields /media/cyprianna/1A48F1D148F/data and `/etc/fstab` yields bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied.

Comment: if the first word of the command you enter is a filename (to be accurate, if it contains a `/`), the shell tries to execute the file as a program. `/etc/fstab` is just a text file; it doesn't have execute permission and that's why you got that error. To read it you need to call a program to display the contents, such as `cat` (ie `cat /etc/fstab`) or `less` or open the file in a text editor (double click in file browser should do that by default) Please [edit] your question to add the contents of the file (and any other updates), formatting it as code with the `{}` button to make it readable.

Comment: @wjandrea Christa Frodella has replied to your comment giving the location pointed to by the symlink. The output of `lsblk` may also be useful in determining which device to mount if it is connected, I guess?

Answer (score 2):

That's the difference between command line and GUI. The icon you see isn't actually there. Under Ubuntu, typically USB disks and partitions are automatically mounted at `/media/username` folder.

The GUI icon you see on the desktop is just a "shortcut" in a sense, but the actual folder to which the partition is mounted is elsewhere. When you open it in GUI file manager, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> you should see the real path to the mountpoint.

As for the part where you need to `ls Data` please note two things:

1. File and directory names are case sensitive.
2. If you `cd Data` you're telling the shell to enter the Data directory that should be located relative to where your shell is right now, i.e. the current working directory.  Doing `cd ~/Desktop` works because you told it the full path, not relative. When you `cd ~/Desktop; ls Desktop` it won't work - there's no `Desktop` within `~/Desktop`. If you just run `ls` with no arguments, then it will work, because it lists items in the current directory by default

Comment: I inputted `ls` because I need to verify that the data from Windows has been successfully shared with Ubuntu. Ultimately, I need data from folder so I can unzip and concatenate it.

Comment: @ChristaFrodella Ok. Just remember that command line and GUI work through different rules. So if you understand difference between relative and full path in command line, your experience will be so much easier

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right, you are looking to access data folder on your desktop.

Try `cd ~/desktop/data` then `ls` to get the contents of this directory.

If you want to create a shortcut use `ln -s <actual path>`. It says create a shortcut (in linux terms softlink to the actual path) in the current location.

Comment: `cd ~/Desktop/data` produces same error

Comment: Do `cd ~/Desktop/` and then do `ls`. Do you see `data` folder?

Comment: yes. It's red with black background. Which apparently indicates that its a broken link. However, it was working before.

Comment: Did you try this `ln -s <actual path>`? It should fix the broken link problem.